# Update an array object using useState

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Basically what I have are two components, a parent and a child. Through a props I intend to update the state of the parent component. Inside child component I have a function called updateData() which is triggered by a button.

```
const updateData = props.setDataState; 
const thisComponentData = props.dataToUs;
 
const handleUpdateData = () => {
    const getIndex = data.findIndex((item) => item.id === thisComponentData.id);

    data[getIndex].category.vehicles = 1
    data[getIndex].category.vehicles = 2

    return updateData(data)
  };
```

The problem is that even I trigger this function, the state of the parent component doesn't change. My hypothesis is that this isn't identifying the state modification I'm doing.

EDIT

The parent component is basically a functional component in which I props the setDataState.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 
// An api inserts the setData data
  
<Parent
dataToUs={data}
setDataState={(value) => setData(value)}/>
```

Comment: Please could you post both components. At a guess though I would say you need to lift the state up to the parent component https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: You can't internally modify state values (arrays or objects); you'll need to copy them when modifying.

Comment: Done @spirift! Makes sense?

Comment: Could you explain better? @AKX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have two functions named the same: `updateData`.

In your case if `setDataState` is probably a function in parent component, then your function `updateData` should look like this:

```
// This variable name should change
const setDataState = props.setDataState; 
const thisComponentData = props.dataToUs;
        
const updateData = () => {
   const updatedDataArray = data.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === thisComponentData.id) 
          return {
           ...item,
           category: {
              ...item.category,    
              vehicles: 2,
         }
       }
      return item;
    });
    setDataState(updatedDataArray)
};
```

EDIT: Edited code so that it uses .map.

Comment: setDataState is a setState hook on parent component

Comment: You are right. But it was just a typo while I was writing this post, sorry.

Comment: Be careful here as state updates should be immutable. You are mutating the state before setting it. You need to clone the array before editing it

Comment: You could use setDataState(data.map( (_stuff) => {..logic..}). That way you would create a new array, and not mutate original one.

Comment: @RoktSe I edited the code to use .map. Try it out, and let us know how that goes.

Also I used same check as you `item.id === thisComponentData.id`, but in your example `dataToUs` is an array so this check would not work, or if the example should be fixed, please do so I can update my answer as well.

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!